# How to find out aws policy attachment id for terraform import?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to import some existing resource into my state file.

One of them is a policy attachement.

Since the attachment is absent in the state file, if I run `terraform plan` I will see this output:

```
  # aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ec2_adhoc_instance_sqs_policy_attachment will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2_adhoc_instance_sqs_policy_attachment" {
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:policy/import-sqs-read-write-policy"
      + role       = "import-sqs-user"
    }
```

If I want to import it, I need to find out the ID of the attachment:

```
tf -f dev import  aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ec2_adhoc_instance_sqs_policy_attachmen <ID?>
```

However I can't find it from the console:

[image]

And I have trouble running the aws cli,

```
$ aws clouddirectory list-policy-attachments --directory-arn 999999999999 --policy-reference import-sqs-read-write-policy

Error parsing parameter '--policy-reference': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
import-sqs-read-write-policy
```

How can I find out the id of a policy attachment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html) for that resources states that the ID is the combination of the role name and policy ARN, so you would use `import-sqs-user/arn:aws:iam::999999999999:policy/import-sqs-read-write-policy` as the ID.